# Input Reader dictionary on mapreduce.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, yaml

Ive been trying to launch a specific mapreduce straight from the /mapreduce dashboard, but for that I need input reader parameters passed in as a dictionary or I get

`BadReaderParamsError: Input reader parameters should be a dictionary`

The problem is yaml validation won't let me add any kind of nested mapping where I need it.

My mapreduce.yaml looks something like this

```
- name: Read CSV from GCS
  mapper:
    input_reader: mapreduce.input_readers.GoogleCloudStorageLineInputReader
    handler: mapreduce.mapper
    params:
    - name: input_reader
      default: {bucket: gcs-bucket}
```

This only leads me to errors similar to `BadYamlError: in "<string>", line 16, column 25: default: {bucket: gcs-bucket} ^`

I tried several YAML approved sorts of nested mapping, but I might have missed the golden one - or validation is just too harsh.

Is it possible to pass the dictionary through mapreduce.yaml or I'd have to launch this job programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating this custom input reader I came across the `allowed_old` flag on `reader_spec = _get_params(mapper_spec, allow_old=False)` When set to `False` it requires all the input reader parameters to be a dictionary on the parameter input_reader on mapreduce.yaml

Setting `allowed_old` to `True` lets you list all the parameters you need on mapreduce.yaml outside the input_reader parameter.